# Devcon driverfiles * only listing a single entry

Tags: windows, drivers, device-manager, windows-server

I am attempting to run the following command:

```
devcon driverfiles *
```

But I am only receiving a single entry in my output...I have seen this on multiple machines (servers as well as workstations):

> ACPI\ACPI000D\PMI
>       Name: System board
>       No driver information available for the device.
>   1 matching device(s) found.

Any idea why devcon would only be throwing a single entry out?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: According to MSDN, "driverfiles *" should "display the full path and file name of installed INF files and device driver files for the specified devices."

Comment: You are running this command from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: What output from `devcon hwids *`? @Ramhound elevating not required. On my _Windows 8.1 64bit_ (both elevated or not) work with `99 matching device(s) found` recapitulation message.

Comment: There's tons of output from `devcon hwids *`...actually receive `153 matching device(s) found`

Comment: Device Manager can allowed or denyed.  I will wait for an answer by the author.  ["To run DevCon commands on a remote computer, the Group Policy setting must allow the Plug and Play service to run on the remote computer. On computers that run Windows Vista and Windows 7, the Group Policy disables remote access to the service by default. On computers that run WDK 8.1 and WDK 8, the remote access is unavailable."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707(v=vs.85).aspx).  We need more information.

Comment: What about `devcon driverfiles *` _after_ `devcon hwids *` with _tons of output_?

Comment: I really didn't think that would work, but this is crazy, it did list a few other devices....up to 4 matching, then stops on the same "machine.inf"